# How to Edit Function-app Code in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans, azure-function-app, azure-function-app-proxy

I published the Function-App to Azure and I am using Timer Trigger to Schedule the Function-app at a particular time
I want to change the schedule Time how to Edit the Function-App Code

I tried **AppserviceEditor**
it gives an error

```
Failed to save 'function.json': Unable to save "/Function1/function.json". Please try again later. Error code: 409
```

Is there any other process to Edit **Azure-Function-App in Azure portal Itself**

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function#update-the-timer-schedule

Comment: I am using Function-app Version=2 and the above document is about function-app version 3 and still tried the steps but its not working

Comment: when you say "publish", is it from visual studio? or you have created the timer trigger function from the portal?

Comment: From Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below steps to make your Scheduled Expression of your Azure Functions - Timer trigger to be a configurable item so that you can change it easily without code deployment.

1. Use a Binding Expression to configure the schedule as shown below.

```cs
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("**%timer-frequency%**")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

2. Create an **Application Settings** named **timer-frequency** in your Azure Functionapp. Each time you want to change the expression, you can change it in the App Setting within the portal without re-deploy the code.

Note: This technique (Binding Expressions) works eves in Azure Function v2 (and ofcourse in v3).

That's it. You can view the output which gets executed based on the frequency that you set.

If you would like to have a detailed step-by-step tutorial, please have a look here at https://praveenkumarsreeram.com/2020/08/06/azure-functions-timer-triggers-configurable-scheduled-expressions/

Comment: Thanks For the Schedule can you explain how to change the deployed azure function code in the portal

Comment: @KarthikKasula, If you develop the function in the portal, then it is possible to edit the same in the portal. if you have developed and published the code from Visual Studio or any other editor, it gets deployed as .dll files. So, you can't edit the code from portal in this case. Hope it's clear.